# Test a condition on a Map element being iterated in Struts JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am new to struts, and am using (have to stay with it) Struts 1.x.

The map is already being iterated over, I just need to add a

`<c:if>` tag to check if the property of map, let's say `map.isGood = true`.

I did:

```
<c:if test=${map.isGood}>  <!--do stuff--> </c:if>
```

But it threw an exception. This is how the map is defined:

```
<logic:iterate id="fullMap" name="fullMap" scope="request">
      <bean:define id="map" name="map" scope="page" toScope="request" />
```

How can I do what I want, can anyone please help?

**Edit:**

The `fullMap` is a map of maps. Key is string and value is another map.
The `map` is a simple `HashMap<String, String>`.

**Stack trace:**

```
[2017-05-04 13:11:52,352] ERROR ContainerBase             - Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: An error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute "test" with value "${map.isGood}": Unable to find a value for "isGood" in object of class "java.util.TreeMap$Entry" using operator "." (null)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.Evaluator.evaluate(Evaluator.java:131)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.Evaluator.evaluate(Evaluator.java:151)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.support.ExpressionEvaluatorManager.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorManager.java:97)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.IfTag.condition(IfTag.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.ConditionalTagSupport.doStartTag(ConditionalTagSupport.java:106)
    at org.apache.jsp.fragments.mapList_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f1(mapList_jsp.java:830)
    at org.apache.jsp.fragments.mapList_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(mapList_jsp.java:715)
    at org.apache.jsp.fragments.mapList_jsp._jspx_meth_logic_005fpresent_005f1(mapList_jsp.java:473)
    at org.apache.jsp.fragments.mapList_jsp._jspService(mapList_jsp.java:362)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:590)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:614)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
    at org.apache.jsp.layouts.classicLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f6(classicLayout_jsp.java:372)
    at org.apache.jsp.layouts.classicLayout_jsp._jspService(classicLayout_jsp.java:141)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:302)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.brix.web.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.brix.web.security.BRIXAuthFilter.doFilter(BRIXAuthFilter.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.brix.web.security.CheckTokenFilter.doFilter(CheckTokenFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: It threw an exception? Perhaps... posting the stacktrace would be helpful. But if `map` is an actual map there's likely no `isGood` property on it.

Comment: I am setting this property in my extended Action class. `${map.isGood}` is my idea of how it would be, I don't know the actual syntax to get a property named `isGood` from `map` and use it in `<c:if>`

Comment: If it's a property of an object *in* the map then you should be calling it on that object, not the map itself. If it's a property on the *action* then you don't need the map to be involved at all. But we're all just guessing, because you include neither the exception nor the data structure(s) in question.

Comment: I have added data structure details, will need some time for stack trace as I closed the older one and to get a new one (build) takes time. The `map` is inside the `fullMap` and `fullMap` is a request attribute.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have added the stack trace too now.

Comment: Same thing I said before: when you iterate you're getting a TreeMap$Entry, not anything that has an `isGood` property on it--the stack trace tells you precisely what's wrong. Also it's hugely misleading to name a map entry `map`. `map` implies... well, a map.

Comment: @DaveNewton How do I correct it? I am really new to using struts with JSTL and I don't know the syntax. The property is there, I am sure, can you please tell me how do I access it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that the `map` variable had the value (As per my little understanding of Struts), but it is not. It's just an entry. I had to do:

`map.value['isGood']` and it worked as expected.